# Save react-native-check-box status after reload

Tags: react-native

I am building a React Native Iphone App.I have a checkbox "Remember me" in Login page, which I want to set to remember the username and password in order to login.I want to save the status of checkbox even after reload(Once it is ticked it should persist till it is ticked-off by the user).Below is my code.

index.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View,KeyboardAvoidingView, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react- 
 native';
import CheckBox from 'react-native-check-box';
import AsyncStorage  from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

  export default class index extends Component{

  constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
  status: false 
  };

toggleStatus = async() =>{
  this.setState({
    status: !this.state.status
  });
  AsyncStorage.setItem("myCheckbox",JSON.stringify(this.state.status));
}

}
componentWillMount(){
AsyncStorage.getItem('myCheckbox').then((value) => {
  this.setState({
    status: (value === 'true')
  });
});
}


render() {

return (
  
  <KeyboardAvoidingView 
  style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}} 
  behavior="padding" 
  keyboardVerticalOffset={50}
  enabled>
  
   <Text>{typeof this.state.status +' : '+ this.state.status}</Text>
    
   <CheckBox
   style={{flex: 1,paddingLeft:100,paddingTop:20}}
   onClick={()=>{
   this.setState({
       isChecked:!this.state.isChecked
       
    })
   toggleStatus(this)
    }}
   isChecked={this.state.isChecked}
   rightText={"Remember me"}
    />


  
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
);
}
}

 index.navigationOptions = {
 headerTitle: ''
 };

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 

 });
```

I could save the status but not set it after reload.I have tried some techniques using the stackoverflow logics, but dint give me proper result.Can anyone help me to set the checkbox.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making a mistake in your toggle method. `async` doesn't work here (Also we need to use `await` with `async`) you should write your code like this. setState take time to save the state so you need to use its callback function which called after the state saved.
I am showing 2 ways here but I prefer the first one.

```
toggleStatus =() =>{
  this.setState({
    status: !this.state.status
  }, () => AsyncStorage.setItem("myCheckbox",JSON.stringify(this.state.status)));
}
```

OR
You can do like

```
toggleStatus = () =>{
  AsyncStorage.setItem("myCheckbox",JSON.stringify(!this.state.status));
  this.setState({
    status: !this.state.status
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried the both of the above functions, but its not working.I checked the checkbox , logged out of the app and on logging in again the checkbox still remains unchecked.SO it is not saving the state.Any other work around?

Comment: Are you able to save and access value from AsyncStorage?

If you don't know put a try catch blow and also try to debug to confirm.

Comment: I could make it work. In the above code I had not set the value of IsChecked to status,  I changed isChecked={this.state.status}    instead of   isChecked={this.state.isChecked}   .Now the checkbox holds the status until we change.